# append url for JSON array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a JSON field in my MySQL table column which has an JSON array with part of images URLs.

```
"images": [
            {
              "images": {
                 "original": "/storage/uploads/1.png",
                 "300": "/storage/uploads/300.1.png",
                 "600": "/storage/uploads/600.1.png",
                 "900": "/storage/uploads/900.1.png"
                    },
               "thumb": "/storage/uploads/300.1.png"
            },
            {
               "images": {
                  "original": "/storage/uploads/2.png",
                  "300": "/storage/uploads/300.2.png",
                  "600": "/storage/uploads/600.2.png",
                  "900": "/storage/uploads/900.2.png"
                    },
                "thumb": "/storage/uploads/300.2.png"
             },
             {},
           ]
```

I want to get the array with appending a Base URL for each of the values of the array.

```
    "images": [
            {
              "images": {
                 "original": "http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/1.png",
                 "300": "http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/300.1.png",
                 "600": "http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/600.1.png",
                 "900": "http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/900.1.png"
                    },
               "thumb": "http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/300.1.png"
            },
            {
               "images": {
                  "original": "http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/2.png",
                  "300": "http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/300.2.png",
                  "600": "http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/600.2.png",
                  "900": "http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/900.2.png"
                    },
                "thumb": "http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/300.2.png"
             },
             {},
           ]
```

I have tried with Collections function like below code. But was not succeeded.

```
'images' => collect($item->images)->map(function ($image) {
                return url($image);
             })->all(),
```

Comment: Do you have an idea for this question? @babak-ashrafi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For collections you would need to create a collection of the second `images` keyed array as well. `collect()` does not create a recursive collection.

So if you had the following array:

```php
$item = [
    "images" => [
        [
            "images" => [
                "original" => "/storage/uploads/1.png",
                "300" => "/storage/uploads/300.1.png",
                "600" => "/storage/uploads/600.1.png",
                "900" => "/storage/uploads/900.1.png"
            ],
            "thumb" => "/storage/uploads/300.1.png",
        ], [
            "images" => [
                "original" => "/storage/uploads/2.png",
                "300" => "/storage/uploads/300.2.png",
                "600" => "/storage/uploads/600.2.png",
                "900" => "/storage/uploads/900.2.png",
            ],
            "thumb" => "/storage/uploads/300.2.png",
        ]
    ]
];
```

and you really wanted to use collection, then the following would work:

```php
$item = collect($item['images'])->map(function ($item) {
    $images = collect($item['images'])->map(function ($item) {
        return url($item);
    });
  
    return [
        "images" => $images->toArray(),
        "thumb"  => url($item['thumb']),
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested foreach to solve this

```
$json = json_decode($item->images, true); // I'm using true to convert the json to array

$images = [];

foreach ($json as $index => $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            foreach ($value as $path_key => $path) {
                $images[$index][$key][$path_key] = url($value[$path_key]);
            }
        } else {
            $images[$index][$key] = url($value);
        }
    }
}
```

If you `dd($images);` you will get

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "images" => array:4 [▼
      "original" => "http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/1.png"
      300 => "http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/300.1.png"
      600 => "http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/600.1.png"
      900 => "http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/900.1.png"
    ]
    "thumb" => "http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/300.1.png"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "images" => array:4 [▼
      "original" => "http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/2.png"
      300 => "http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/300.2.png"
      600 => "http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/600.2.png"
      900 => "http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/900.2.png"
    ]
    "thumb" => "http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/300.2.png"
  ]
]
```